# Why does mod_revite not work in Apache?

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, debian

I am have: Apache 2.4.2 on Debian Linux 9. Apache was install from standard repository, and mod_rewrite too.

The root of the site is: **/var/www/mysite**.
The virtual host **local-mysite.ru** is configured for this directory.

For a start, I put to the root index.php-file with the call to phpinfo (). I I checked this output: in the Loaded Modules section I see mod_rewrite. It's good.

Next, I unpack a test site. Here start script is opened by the following URL:
    http://local-mysite.ru/appadv/frontend/web
and on this URL, too normal opens:
    http://local-mysite.ru/appadv/frontend/web/index.php

Now, I need that when the browser opens **http://local-mysite.ru**, followed the redirect to the URL **http://local-mysite.ru/appadv/frontend/web**.

For this, I wrote .htaccess with this content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# If the request does not start with the web, we add it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(appadv/frontend/web)
RewriteRule (.*) /appadv/frontend/web/$1

# If the file or directory does not exist, go to /web/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /appadv/frontend/web/index.php
```

I tested him in the online tester http://htaccess.madewithlove.be. There the transformation URI goes right.

**But on my host URI conversion does not happen!**

For debugging, I edited the option in the **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** file to see the redirect messages:

```
LogLevel warn rewrite: trace4
```

Rebooted Apache. Updated the page with the URL http://local-mysite.ru. As far as I understand, lines marked with [rewrite ...] or something like this should appear in the file **/var/log/apache2/error.log**. But there is nothing like that.

I do not know where to dig any more.

If it's important: by the URL **http://local-mysite.ru** the Apache shows a list of files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file requires set AllowOverride option from None to All for /var/www/ directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```